# Set Woocommerce woocommerce_get_refreshed_fragments call admin-ajax.php run after page loads

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, pageload, admin-ajax

I optimzed my site with cahce and it speeds to about 2 sec load time.
The problem is that even that everything is done loading, but there are is 2 ajax call to admin-ajax.php with a action called woocommerce_get_refreshed_fragments that slows the load in another 3- 4 seconds.
Is there is a way to set to run this action after page load completed?
Something like

```
add_action("print_woocommerce_get_refreshed_fragments_script","after_load" )
```

(only example). Or any other idea to solve this and make this call to admin-ajax.php after page done loading.
Thanks.
The function appears here https://github.com/jpBenfica/woocommercePT/blob/master/woocommerce-ajax.php

Comment: Did you ever find a fix? This is a major issue adding 2+ seconds to the page load time and I can't believe you have no replies!

Comment: @benb Hello did you found solution for trigger that function after page fully loaded